# MongoDB. Is it possible to create value with string

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using mongodb with aggregation framework and I need to somehow pass in my query value with some string.

I need something like this:

```
{
  '$project' => {
       'value' => '$value',
       'label' => 'Some string'
     }
 }
```

And in result I should have the following:

```
{
   value => 'value of $value',
   label => 'Some string'
}
```

I have to use only aggregation framework.

Comment: what programming language do you use? it's not quite clear what do you mean by "pass the $value". using the notation with dollar sign as you provided, it means either some build in function or field name of the document

Comment: @VolodymyrMetlyakov I'm using Ruby language. The `$value` it is simple  field in my document which I want fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shell you can use this "solution":

```
t = "Some text..."
db.towns.aggregate([
    {'$project': {"nm" : "$name", "text": {$substr : [t,0, t.length]}}}
])
```

You only need to adapt for your programming language.

Comment: Hi @Gh0stik, this one `{$substr : [t,0, t.length]}` works for me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

independently of the programming language, and before [$literal](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5782) is there, you can use for example $concat to assign static value to projection (how to define is as parameter depends actually on the PL/driver that you use):

```
{
  '$project' : {
       'value' : {$concat: ['$value']} ,
       ....
     }
 }
```